# Subtyping among generic interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, generics, subtyping

I have a "minimal state" type that contains some data and can generate another instance of minimal state:

```
public interface IMinimalState
{
   IMinimalState generate();
   int getData();
}
```

I also have a "normal state" that contains more data and can generate an instance of normal state:

```
public interface IState
{
   IState generate();
   int getData();
   int getAnotherData();
}
```

As far as I can tell, IState should be a subtype of IMinimalState. (Anything that requires an IMinimalState should be just as happy when it gets an IState) However, I cannot get the compiler to accept that.

Example:

```
   public interface IMinimalState
   {
      IMinimalState generate();
      int getData();
   }

   public interface IState : IMinimalState
   {
      int getAnotherData();
   }

   public class MinimalState : IMinimalState
   {
      public IMinimalState generate() { return this; }
      public int getData() { return 0; }
   }

   public class State : IState
   {
      public IState generate() { return this; }  //Compiler Error, return type should be IMinimalState
      public int getData() { return 1; }
      public int getAnotherData() { return 2; }
   }
```

Fair enough, let's try generic interfaces:

```
   public interface IMinimalState<out T> where T : IMinimalState<T>
   {
      T generate();
      int getData();
   }

   public interface IState<out T> : IMinimalState<T> where T : IState<T>
   {
      int getAnotherData();
   }

   public class MinimalState : IMinimalState<MinimalState>
   {
      public MinimalState generate() { return this; }
      public int getData() { return 0; }
   }

   public class State : IState<State>
   {
      public State generate() { return this; }
      public int getData() { return 1; }
      public int getAnotherData() { return 2; }
   }
```

No compiler errors yet. But `State` is still not a subtype of `MinimalState`, and `IState<State>` is not a subtype of `IMinimalState<MinimalState>`. I tried many other combinations but had no success.

Is there a way to make `IState` a subtype of `IMinimalState`? If not,

- is it because .Net type system is not powerful enough?
- or, am I wrong to think that `IState` is really a subtype of `IMinimalState`? (Is there a scenario when the program will crash if something that requires an `IMinimalState` receives a `IState`?)

Comment: Do you not want to have `State` inherit from `MinimalState` and override `generate()` ?

Comment: State and MinimalState have very different implementations. (I simplified the question; they don't just "return this")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use new keyword to change the return type of `generate`, and then implement both variations of `generate` in `State` class

```
   public interface IMinimalState
   {
      IMinimalState generate();
      int getData();
   }

   public interface IState : IMinimalState
   {
      new IState generate();      
      int getAnotherData();
   }

   public class State : IState
   {
      public IState generate() { return this; } 
      IMinimalState IMinimalState.generate() { return  generate(); }           
      ...
   }
```

Comment: State and MinimalState classes have very different implementations, (I simplified; they don't "return this") so State cannot be a subclass of MinimalState.

Comment: Thank you, yes it works. I'm still a little unhappy about using "new" keyword though. I'd like to be able to define generate as a method that return a value of the same type as "self". (Probably the fault lies in .Net Type System being not powerful enough) I'm waiting for a couple of days to see if someone provides more insight about the limitations of the type system; then I'll accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the return type - you're changing `the contract` - you can't model that with `IMinimalState`.

I'd just simplify a bit e.g.

```
public interface IMinimalState
{
    IMinimalState generate();
    int getData();
}

public interface IState : IMinimalState
{
    // IState generate();
    int getAnotherData();
}

public class MinimalState : IMinimalState
{
    public IMinimalState generate() { return this; }
    public int getData() { return 0; }
}

public class State : IState
{
    IMinimalState IMinimalState.generate() { return this.generate(); }
    // IState IState.generate() { return this; }
    public IState generate() { return this; }
    public int getData() { return 1; }
    public int getAnotherData() { return 2; }
}
```

**Note: your 'use-case' is essential here** (and missing) - and drives your design. You should always supply that prior to making design decision, probably the first thing to do.

Normally if you're storing and iterating over the base interface `IMinimalState` - that's all you need.

If you're accessing the object `knowing` that it's `State` you can use its public method for that to get the strong-type.

If you'd still want - you can have both (just uncomment the two lines).

And the last option - often used in more complex cases - **is to use a `Visitor` to differentiate in between IMinimalState and IState** - when you have just a list of base interfaces. E.g. that's used by expressions where you need to `redefine` types of parameters, sub-expressions etc. If you're interested I can post that later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return IMinimalState because this is what the interface says.

```
public class State : IState
{
  public IMinimalState generate() { return this; }  // Fixed
  public int getData() { return 1; }
  public int getAnotherData() { return 2; }
}
```

If you later need to access the IState members on a reference of IMinimalState you need to cast it

```
var state = minimalState as IState;
if (state != null)
{
    // Work on IState
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but I think the price is too high. An implementation of `IState` should always generate an object of type `IState`, not `IMinimalState`. We failed to document that constraint in the code, and had to use casting and run time type checks.

Comment: Then why not apply a factory pattern here instead?

Comment: I do have different classes that uses `IState` and `IMinimalState` objects respectively, but then I want them to have a subtype relation too. Which is impossible until I make `IState` a subtype of `IMinimalState`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics:

```
public interface IMinimalState<T>
{
    T generate();
    int getData();
}

public interface IState : IMinimalState<IState>
{
    IState generate();
    int getAnotherData();
}
```

Comment: (After adding `new` keyword to generate) this still does not work: Suppose we have an implementation `MinimalState` of type `IMinimalState<MinimalState>` and an implementation `State` of type `IState`, you cannot assign a `State` to variable of type `MinimalState`.